# Глупая сортировка, вывод простых чисел

Tags: c#, сортировка, простые-числа

Необходимо отсортировать рандомный массив глупой сортировкой, а после уже из отсортированного массива вывести все простые числа.

Кое-какой код составил, но виснет на выводе простых чисел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему?

Код прилагается.

```
using System;

namespace StupidSort {
class Program {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {
        int[] array = new int[100];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            array[i] = rand.Next(0,100); // заполняем массив рандомами

        Console.WriteLine("Исходная последовательность: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) // вывод исходного массива
            Console.Write(array[i] + " ");

        stupidsort(array); // сортировка

        Console.WriteLine("\nОтсортированная последовательность: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) // вывод отсортированного массива
            Console.Write(array[i] + " ");


        search_simple_numb(array);

        Console.Read();

        }
    static void stupidsort(int[] arr ) { // сортировка
        int i = 0, tmp;
        while (i < arr.Length - 1) {
            if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i]) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                i -= i;
            }
            else i++;
        }
    }
    static void search_simple_numb( int[] arr ) {
        Console.WriteLine("\nПростые числа:");
        int i = 0, tmp;
        while (i < arr.Length - 1) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) // отбрасываем четные числа
                continue;
            else if  (arr[i] == 1 || arr[i] == 3 || arr[i] == 5){ // 1,3,5 выводим сразу
                Console.Write(" "+arr[i] +" ");
                }
            else {
                for (int x = 1; x < arr[i]-1; x += 2 ) { // 
                    tmp = arr[i] %= x;
                    if (tmp == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    Console.Write(" " + arr[i] + " ");
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависает из-за этих строк

```
int i = 0;
while (i < arr.Length - 1) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
      continue;
    // ...   
    i++;
}
```

Из-за сontinue, значение i не увеличивается, вызывается while. А т.к. значение arr[i] прежнее, то опять вызывается continue.
Замените код на следующий:

```
int i = -1;
while (++i < arr.Length - 1) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
      continue;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, ваш цикл `while` в методе `search_simple_numb` становится вечным, как только встречает четное число.
Обратите внимание, что внутри условного блока

```
if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) // отбрасываем четные числа
    continue;
```

вы переходите к следующему шагу цикла, но при этом значение переменной `i` не изменено.

Предлагаю заменить цикл `while` на `for`.
То есть меняем это:

```
int i = 0, tmp;
while (i < arr.Length - 1) {
```

На это:

```
int tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: неподходит, так как он прогоняет несколько чисел, даже выдает, но только согласно условию "(arr[i] == 1 || arr[i] == 3 || arr[i] == 5)", что то не дает ему уйти в иначе.

Comment: @Rafnsvartr Что не подходит? Как только цикл встречает четное число, он уже *никогда* не попадет на `i++` (из-за оператора `continue`).

Comment: @Rafnsvartr Для теста: просто замените `continue` на пустой блок `{ }`.

Comment: без continue выдает больше чисел, чем без него.

Comment: но все числа в пределах от 1 до 5.

Comment: @Rafnsvartr Значит у вас есть еще ошибки в логике программы. Но проблема с зависанием, на которую вы и жаловались в вопросе, решена.

Comment: @Dmitriy спасибо вам большое, буду дальше разбираться =)